# vb project and c# project in same solution published to same website

Tags: c#, vb.net, iis

I'm converting a massive vb Webforms project to a c# mvc project and using angular for the front end. There is a large portion of the site, like 500 webforms that I would like to just leave as vb webforms. I know its possible to put a vb project and a c# project in the same solution. But can I publish both of them to the same website on IIS and also share authentication? I don't want to have to manage two web domains. I dont want to have go from www.website1.com to www.website2.com. I want both of them in www.website1.com

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Inquiring (managerial) minds would like to know exactly *why* "over 500 webforms," now written in VB, are being converted to "C#," *and(!)* why Angular is being brought into the picture.  Is there actually **business** justification for this effort, given that VB and C# compile into exactly the same bytecode, and both are respectable compilers?

Comment: Thats the problem Im trying to solve. I just threw angular out there, its not really important. The bigger picture is that the angular part is the new redesigned section of the site and I didnt want to build it in vb. I am more comfortable with c# and so is the rest of the development team, but I dont want to convert the whole project if I dont have to. I would like to develope the new sections with C# and leave the rest alone. Thanks

Comment: ... and, as the developing "answers" to this question are beginning to spell out, you can *do* just that. IIS deals only with *compiled* objects, and the two languages compile to the same thing. The only caution that I would add here is that, in your developing C# application, you should develop a few "mitten" *(my term ...)* classes that will allow you to handle the VB-components easily. The C# language embodies many programming concepts that the VB language knows not of. In your C# application, devise a class to shield one from the other, for robustness. ("Details are up to you." **;-)**)

Comment: Ill keep that in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Both languages (VB.NET and C#) will be compile to the IL code so for IIS there is no difference between libraries developed in those two languages. You can even refer from one library to another and don't bother about theirs original source langauge.

Comment: So just drop the contents of both published projects into the same wwwroot folder? what about web.configs? Do you think it will matter if there are two?

Comment: Yes, it probabily will matter in this case. You have to look in both web.config and merge it (for example there are different connection strings for databases). Then merge projects in one solution with one web.config but you can don't bother about projects languages. If you can't simply merge it then try to put one subapplication inside the other in separate subfolder and run it like http://yourdomain/subfolder (the main app will use simply http://yourdomain) - because they will use the same domain then you can use the same cookie for session.